# How are Groovy GDK enhancements to Java Collections implemented?

Tags: java, groovy, programming-languages

Specifically, if we create a POJO like `def a = new java.util.HashSet<Integer>()`, and then call `a.sum()`, how does this work? We can see that the Groovy GDK's version of `java.util.Iterable<T>` contains a `sum()` method. My question is: how is a GDK enhancement function call like `sum()` called on a POJO get dispatched to Groovy's implementation of `sum()`.

Comment: In short - groovy dynamically looking for a method in groovy metaclass before java class. Your question too wide to answer...

Comment: When a.sum() is compiled it is tied to ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethod(a,”sum”) in typical cases. It is this method that starts off dynamic resolution of “sum”. In static compile mode, the extension method is resolved and the bytecode invokes it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Going way back Groovy had a concept of a dynamic mixin where it added a metaClass property onto the Class objects of the JDK.  You could dynamically add methods to a class following this pattern:

```
 class Base64Mixin {
     static String base64Encode( String self ) {
         Base64Encoder encoder = new Base64Encoder("UTF-8")
         return encoder.encode( self )
     }
 }
 String.mixin Base64Mixin

 String myBase64 = "blahblahblahblahblah".base64Encode()
 println( myBase64 )
```

That was how it was done in the early days of Groovy.  In 2.3 Traits were released which might change this a little, but I think it's still done this way by modifying the metaClass object to add the functions that way.

Static compilation is performed differently using AST Transformations and the `@Mixin` annotation.  However, since `@Mixin` is placed on the class being mixed into (ie String in the example above) you can't use it to modify the JDK classes.  But, @Mixin is deprecated in favor of using Traits.